# Simple form for not working on belongs to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, has-many, belongs-to

Hello I have a simple rails app that has two models a goal and a task

The goal has many tasks, and a task belongs to a goal.

For some reason, probably a rookie error, I cannot get the form to the task form to render with simple form.

Models

Goal

```
class Goal < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks
end
```

Task

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :goal
end
```

Controllers

Goals

```
class GoalsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_goal, only: [:show]

  def show
  end

  private

  def set_goal
    @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

View views/goals/show

```
<div class="row">
  <%= @goal.title %> 
<div class="row">
  <ul>
    <% @goal.tasks.each do |task| %>
    <li><%= task.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <%= render partial: 'tasks/form', locals: {comment: @goal.tasks.new} %>
</div>
```

Form views/tasks/_form

```
<%= simple_form_for([@goal, @task]) do |f| %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I get the error `NoMethodError` in Goals#show

so obviously I need to add the @task to my goals show.... but how

so I added to my goals show method

```
@task = Task.find_or_create_by(:task_id)
```

then i get the error

```
Unsupported argument type: task_id (Symbol)
```

so I added the following to my goals_controller

```
def show
  @task = Goal.task.find_or_create_by(:task_id)
end
```

but then I get

```
NoMethodError in GoalsController#show
undefined method `task' for #<Class:0x00007ff8c79b0920> Did you mean? take
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :tasks
  resources :goals
end
```

Comment: What do you expect this form should do?

Comment: @Gabbar create a task associated with the goal... belongs to goal

Comment: Do you have nested routes for tasks?

Comment: no because I want the user to have access to their current_user.tasks.all as a list

Comment: Can you show your routes?

Comment: Added the routes... all very basic. this is not nested

Comment: What is `comment`? You pass it as local (and it is a task object; weird) and never use it.

Comment: Try adding `@task = @goal.tasks.build` in `goals_controller#show`.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I am not sure what you are saying in your first comment

Comment: @JagdeepSingh your second comment is correct.... what is the difference with build and create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Jagdeep's comment above adding Try adding @task = @goal.tasks.build in goals_controller#show fixed this issue.

hope this helps